# How to test method in controller with logged user

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I need test method in controller and i need to have logged user.
My code is:

```
private $client;
private $reflectionOfClientsController;
private $clientsController;

public function setUp()
{
    $this->client = static::createClient();
    $this->clientsController = new ClientsController();
    $this->reflectionOfClientsController = new \ReflectionClass('Vendor\AdministrationBundle\Controller\ClientsController');
}

public function testGetLoggedUserId(){
    $user = new User('superadmin', 'superadmin', array('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'));
    $this->login($user);


    $method = $this->reflectionOfClientsController->getMethod('getLoggedUserId');
    $method->setAccessible(true);

    $this->assertEquals('null', $method->invokeArgs($this->clientsController, array()));
}

private function login($user){
    $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');

    $firewall = 'secured_area';
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), $firewall, $user->getRoles());
    $session->set('_security_'.$firewall, serialize($token));
    $session->save();

    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
}
```

if I call

```
phpunit -c app/
```

then I get error

```
Call to a member function has() on a non-object in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php on line 238
```

I know, I have user logged in client, but I don't know, how to get him into $clientsController